# How to use plugin in my own application in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I want to use a pluging for file upload and create thumbnail in cakephp `http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader` for my own website. But I am not able to understand the documentation.

if you have better pluging then suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

There is an entire section about "pluging" in the CakePHP book / documentation:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html